# Clear field on Focus & Submit

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a form setup with 2 text boxes that have default values that can be cleared on focus. The boxes are optional not compulsary. So ultimatley the form can be submitted without them, But when the form is submitted with the default values set it appears to pass them on POST.

Is there anyway to clear them from the post data and submit them as NULL / Blank values.

My form code is as follows :

```
<input id="town" name="SeV[2]"  type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 149px; color:#ccc;" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Town / City') this.style.color = '#000'; { this.value = ''; }" value="Enter Town / City" class="field">

<input type="text" style="width: 149px; color:#ccc;" maxlength="255" name="SeV[4]" onfocus="if(this.value == 'e.g Football') this.style.color = '#000'; { this.value = ''; }" value="e.g Football">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use HTML5's `placeholder="Enter Town / City"` if your users are primarily using updated browsers.  http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code and it should work fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $("input:text", $(this)).each(function(index) {
            if (this.value === this.defaultValue)
                this.value = "";
        });
    });
});
```

It will iterate over all text boxes upon form submission and set their value to empty if equals to their default value.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/PbvYw/3/). (Click submit and see the default values are being cleared, if you change a value it will stay)

Comment: I can see it working in your test. Thats exactly what I need, However putting it into my site, Its not working..? Form info is below..

<form action="" name="MemberSearch" method="post" id="MemberSearch">

Comment: You probably don't have the `type="text"` in the `<input>` tags, as this is the default it's my bad.. see the edit for a fix. I've also fixed bug with multiple forms that would have cleared values in forms not being submitted so the code now deals only with the elements in the submitted form..

Comment: Ah ha! Its triggering, But the form isnt submitting now.. ?

When I click the submit button. The form doesnt submit, It clears the values but doesnt run the submit?

Comment: Make sure you don't have the `return false;` line I have in the test case, it's canceling the form submission.